# git installation failing, windows 10

Tags: windows-10, git

Have been  getting weird errors on my dev machine since the last windows update, exemplified by git failing to install :

[image: first error]

And also cryptovoxels website not working in chrome or edge (a 3D webgl site), but it is working in firefox. Do they use different rendering engines ?

I have tried a fresh install of windows but still get the same problems, is my cpu borked ?

All my hardware *seems* fine : memtest performed windows and mem96, intel diagnostic tool, ssd check - all passing without problem.

(apologies if this isn't the best place to ask)

Previously tried a restore [Win 10, after april 14 update unuseable. RefreshWindowsTool.exe won't open, MediaCreationTool20H2.exe unuseable](https://superuser.com/q/1645349/29392).

Seriously going to get a Mac.

Comment: _"Do they use different rendering engines?"_ - yes.

Comment: Did you try googling the error, as it appears application-specific?

Comment: @JW0914 its not application specific. Numerous apps have failed in different ways, I've highlighted two that obvious and repeatable.  Googling floating point error gets me, well nowhere useful.

Comment: @gronostaj well thanks, I think.  Care to elaborate on how they interact with windows/the cpu and what the differences are so I can track down the problem.

Comment: @NimChimpsky What I meant by application-specific was from the returned results it appears to not be an OS issue _(corroborates a clean install not fixing the issue, coupled with the results going back years with varying OS versions)_, but specific to applications themselves. One returned result I skimmed through implied graphics drivers may be at fault.

Comment: I'm not that knowledgeable about exact differences, but it's enough to say that it's completely different code. Chrome and Edge use the Blink rendering engine and V8 JS engine, while Firefox uses Gecko and SpiderMonkey. They have nothing in common.

Comment: @JW0914 I have tried it with intel onboard graphics, and also with my graphics card.  Same result.  The git install doesn't look like a graphics driver issue ? But hey I'm completely lost, have been since last week with it.